# plot.xts() x-axis Tick Label Format and y-axis Label [R]

Tags: r, plot, xts

Asking a follow-up question about `plot.xts()` formatting.  I asked a similar question a few minutes ago which was answered adequately.  Code and printout are included below:

```
## Reformat UST time series
ust <- merge.xts(us.3m, us.6m, us.2y, us.3y, us.5y, us.10y, us.30y)

## Generate color schema for plot
asdf <- as.zoo(ust)
tsRainbow = rainbow(ncol(asdf))

## Plot bond yield evolution graph
plot.xts(ust, screens=1,
         major.ticks="years",
         main="U.S. Bond Yield Evolution", ylab="Bond Yield (%)",
         major.format="%Y",
         yaxis.right=FALSE, yaxis.left=TRUE,
         grid.ticks.on="years", col=tsRainbow)
## Add legend to graph using same color schema
addLegend("topright", 
          legend.names=c("US 3M", "US 6M", "US 2Y", "US 3Y", "US 5Y", "US 10Y", "US 30Y"),
          col=tsRainbow, 
          lty=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1), lwd=c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2),
          ncol=2, bg="white", bty="o")
```

[image: Current graph]

I would like to accomplish the following:

1. Add y-axis label, called `"Bond Yield (%)"`
2. Make x-axis tick labels have a year-only format.  Instead of seeing `"Jan 01 1997"`, I would like to see `"1997"` below the labelled tick marks.

I attempted to accomplish task 1 using the traditional `ylab` argument in the `plot.xts()` call.  I attempted to accomplish the second task using the `major.format` argument in the `plot.xts()` call.  Clearly, neither of these workarounds were successful.

I believe there is likely a simple solution to this problem.  However, I am not well-versed in plotting `xts` datasets, and would appreciate some help.

Comment: For (2), the best I can come up with is converting your x-axis to as.yearqtr() from zoo. It'll show as (20XX-Q1).